# Extract Object From Response Entity

Tags: java, json, resttemplate, response-entity

I am working to hit API through Rest Template and I have successfully received the response in responseEntity form. Now my requirement is to extract values from response to my object.

```
String uri = "http://192.168.1.113:10100/scf/reset";
String str = "ship";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
        
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
map.add("scfType", str);

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange( uri, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
```

And I have response in the form of JSON

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "status": "OK",
    "payload": {
        "channelItemId": 41179181,
        "itemQuantity": 6,
        "date_Created": "2022-08-23T21:40:52.412+0000",
        "date_Modified": "2022-09-20T11:15:40.859+0000",
        "deleted": false,
        "user_Id": 2075
}
```

I have my object which is

```
ChannelItem channelItem = new ChannelItem();
```

My requirement is to get values which are in `payload` and store them in `channelItem`.

Answer (score 0):

> Use `ParameterizedTypeReference` instead of `String`
> Learn more: [Rest Template with ParameterizedTypeReference](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-json-list#3-resttemplate-with-user-list-and-parameterizedtypereference)

```java
ResponseEntity<ChannelItem> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, request, new ParameterizedTypeReference<ChannelItem>() {});
ChannelItem channelItem = response.getBody();
```

Comment: I have tried it already but getting this syntax error. ```The method exchange(String, HttpMethod, HttpEntity<?>, Class<T>, Object...) in the type RestTemplate is not applicable for the arguments (String, HttpMethod, HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,String>>, new ParameterizedTypeReference<ChannelItem>(){})```